# How can I target a specific version of the C++ runtime?

Tags: .net, c++, side-by-side

We have a very large project mostly written in C# that has some small, but important, components written in C++. We target the RTM of .NET 2.0 as the minimum required version. So far, in order to meet this requirement we've made sure to have only the RTM of .NET 2.0 on our build box so that the C++ pieces link against that version.

**Update:** The C++ assembly that is causing the issue is a mixed-mode C++ assembly being loaded into a managed process.

Unfortunately when the confiker was set to do something on April 1st, our corporate IT made a huge push to get everything patched and up to date, and as a result everything up through 3.5 SP1 got installed on the build box. We've tried uninstalling everything, which has happened before, but now we are unable to meet our minimum requirements as anything built on that particular box requires .NET 2.0 SP1.

Since the box seems to be hosed in that we can't just uninstall the offending versions, is there any way to build the assemblies and explicitly tell them to use the RTM of .NET 2.0 (which is v2.0.50727.42)? I've seen pages that refer to using a manifest, but I can't figure out how to actually implement a proper manifest and get it into the assemblies. My expertise is in the managed world, so I'm at a bit of a loss on this.

Can anyone explain how I can make these assemblies target the .NET 2.0 RTM SxS assemblies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I'm pretty sure that Christopher's answer and code sample (thank you, Christopher!) is part of a more elegant solution, we were under the gun to get this out the door and found a very similar, but different, solution.

The first step is to create a manifest for the assembly:

```
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT' version='8.0.50608.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50608.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Next you have to set the 'Generate Manifest' option to 'No' under Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Manifest File, and set the 'Embed Manifest' option to 'No' under Configuration Properties -> Manifest Tool -> Input and Output.

Finally, to get your new manifest into the assembly add the following command to the project's post-build step:

```
mt.exe /manifest "$(ProjectDir)cppassembly.dll.manifest" /outputresource:"$(TargetDir)\cppassembly.dll";#2 -out:"$(TargetDir)\cppassembly.dll.manifest"
```

Once built we can open the dll in Visual Studio to view the manifest under RT_MANIFEST and confirm that it has our manifest!

When I put Christopher's code in the stdafx.h it ended up adding it as an *additional* dependency...the manifest was still looking for v8.0.50727.762. The manifest it generated looked like this:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT" version="8.0.50608.0" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT" version="8.0.50727.762" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" version="8.0.50727.762" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

I could not track down another switch that would remove or clear existing dependencies. I like Christopher's approach better than a post-build step, but for now this works. If anyone has any additional input on how to clear out any existing dependencies that'd be great.

Thanks!

Comment: John, I was able to get this solution to work without the build step (in VS 2005.)  In the project settings Manifest Tool -> Input and Output -> Embed Manifest to Yes, then change the Output Manifest File to the name of the file you are using.  In my case I put the manifest in the project directory (same as .vcproj directory), included it in the project files, and simply entered the name without a path.  I confirmed that the manifest is embedded as is, without the generated dependencies.  It fixed my problem!  Fantastic!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In your project properties, there is a page that indicates the runtime.  There is a drop down that lists all of the runtimes available.  Choose the one that is appropriate for you.
(For VS 2008: Right click on the project -> properties, Compile tab, Advanced Compiler Settings button -> Target framework)

We do this right now.  We would like to move to VS 2008, but we are doing it incrementally.  So right now we have a VS 2008 solution, but all the projects still target .Net 2.0.  Thus, when we compile and deploy, we don't need the .Net 3.5 stuff installed on our test boxes.

**UPDATE:**

To force a native program to link to specific versions of .dlls, you probably want to use something like this:

```
#pragma message ("Explicit link to generate a manifest entry for MFC.")

#if defined (_DEBUG)

#pragma comment(linker, "\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.DebugMFC' version='8.0.50608.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b'\"")

#else

#pragma comment(linker, "\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.MFC' version='8.0.50608.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b'\"")

#endif
```

Except, that instead of MFC, you should find the correct values for the .Net .DLLs.

It is reasonable to believe that you cannot have .Net 2.0 SP1 and .Net 2.0 on the same box.  So getting this to work on that box is likely going to be really, really painful.  It is probably better to spin up a new build VM that you can install the old, unpatched .Net framework on (if you can even get a hold of it anymore.)

Otherwise you will need to copy all the build-time files over to your current box, and then make adjustments to the include and library paths based on your build type.  Probably this is a much bigger headache than it's worth.

Comment: I believe that only works for .Net projects. I don't think that works for a unmanaged C++ project. I've always found Visual Studio to target the latest version of the runtime when compiling C++ code.

Comment: Correct...that only works for managed projects. I wish it were that easy for unmanaged. :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted managed C++.  You can do similar things for native C++ by choosing which SDK you are targetting.  This basically involves setting the correct compiler paths.  For VS2005 there is a batch file called vcvars.bat  

Are you using makefiles to build, or devenv?

Comment: We are using MSBuild, which under the hood is calling vcbuild for the VC projects. This certainly looks more like what I think is needed.

Can you clarify where I'd put the code above (I'm not so hot in C++ land)? If I'm understanding your update correctly, does that bit of code actually generate/embed the manifest at build time?

Comment: The code goes in a header file included by all the translation units (C++ code implementation files) that need it.  In reality, it only needs to be in one translation unit per .dll, but I prefer to just put it in the appropriate header. That snippet is a preprocessor directive that tells the compiler to generate a manifest at build time.

Answer (score 3):

John really put me on the right track to solve the same problem.  I am making a slight change to an old VS2005 C++ (non-CLR) project.  My development machine has all the updates so VS2005 was creating references to the latest versions of the MFC80 and MSVCx80 DLLs and the executable wouldn't run on the target machines becuase those versions were not available and I do not have the option to update those machines.  So I need to control the assmelby dependencies in the manifest which is embedded in the executable file.  This seems to be about the same problem John is working on.  Starting with his additional information, this is what worked for me.

In the ProjectDir create **program.exe.debug.manifest** and **program.exe.release.manifest** files with the appropriate assembly reference information.  Do not add these to the project or the linker with try to include both of them in every build.  Then set the project properties as follows:

Linker-> Manifest File options

- Generate Manifest: No
- Manifest File: blank
- Additional Manifest Dependencies: blank
- Allow Isolation: Yes

Manifest Tools->Input and Output options

- Additional Manifest Files: $(ProjectDir)$(TargetFileName).$(ConfigurationName).manifest
- Input Resource Manifests: blank
- Embed Manifest: Yes
- Output Manifest File: (filled in automatically)
- Manifest Resource File: (filled in automatically)
- Generate Catalog Files: No
- Dependency Information File: $(IntDir)\mt.dep (filled in automatically)

From my testing, it appears that this does not generate any other manifest files and embeds your hand coded manifest information into the EXE as RT_MANIFTEST resource #1.

In the Manifest Tool options, “**Output Manifest File**” and “**Manifest Resource File**” were filled in automatically, even after I cleared them.

This seems to allow me to control the assembly dependencies and get the executable to run on the target machines.  The added benefit is that I did not have to use the post-build step which is being used for other purposes.  By manipulating the Linker and Manifest Tool options, it is possible to get the same result.

Sorry I couldn't updoad screen shots, but I am a new user and images are not allowed yet.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a hack,  but i've resorted to generating the manifest externally, and modifying it with notepad. In a pinch, it's done the trick for me.  In my case, i was looking to have a VC++ 2005 app point to a .762 CRT.

Good Luck!
Terry

Answer (score 1):

John's answer works for us.  In Visual C++ 2005, the compiler generates manifests that include both 762 and 4053 versions of MFC and CRT.  We deleted the 4053 version from the manifest, and went to the manual step described above.  (Internally code will actually grab 4053 as it's a recognized security fix over 762, but the spec is necessary or linking will just fail.)

Ted's blog (tedwvc.wordpress.com) posting gave us the hint, but his solution didn't work out for us.  This approach here works.

Answer (score 0):

Methinks you want [`CorBindToRuntime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231419.aspx). This will allow you to specify the version of the CLR your C++ loads.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something I don't think that's what we're looking for. The CorBindToRuntime appears to be an unmanaged API to bring managed code into an unmanaged process. The executable, and most of application, is managed C#. The assembly we're trying to load into the managed process is a mixed-mode C++ assembly.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Ah. Most of the interop I've dealt with has been going the other way. You're right, this probably won't help unless you rearchitect the app to have an unmanaged executable that loads the managed code.